# jQuery Dom manipulation .append()

Tags: jquery, dom

Hey guys i have some code here that is supposed to do the following: appends image to the DOM using jquery, my example is also done using native js.

My problem is i don't know jquery enough to get a new image placed on the DOM with the click of the button for jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
// native js
<script>
var $ = function (id)   
{                       
   return document.getElementById(id);
}               
var showImg = function () {
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('container');
div.appendChild(img);
img.src = "http://www.palomar.edu/images/assets/pclogo.jpg";
};
window.onload = function ()
{
$("showImgJavaScript").onclick = showImg;       
}
</script>

// jquery
<script> 
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#showImgjQuery").click(function() {

        $( "div.image" ).append("<img src='http://www.palomar.edu/images/assets/pclogo.jpg'>");
    });

});
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="container"> 
    <p>Image goes here </p> 
</div> 
<div id="image"> 
    <p> Some other content goes here </p> 
</div> 
</body> 
<input type="button" id="showImgJavaScript" value="Insert Image--DOM">
<input type="button" id="showImgjQuery" value="Insert Image--jQuery">

</html>
```

Comment: why do you have `var $ = function (id)   
{                       
   return document.getElementById(id);
}     `

Comment: just a neat shortcut for document.getElementsByID @ArunPJohny

Comment: @user2872778 that I understood wast just wondering why jQuery as included...

Comment: Why you use HTML elements after `</body>` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `.image` should be `#image` cause you use `ID` not a `CLASS`
2. **Scope.** Your `$` alias is being used by your JS vanilla function therefore polluting the global name space where the `$` is used by the window.jQuery as alias for (exactly!) jQuery.

### 2 solutions:

For the `document.ready` function shorthand `$(functon(){` set the function name as `jQuery`, and pass the `$` alias as function argument :

```
jQuery(function( $ ) { // DOM READY and secured $ (jQuery) alias
```

now the `$` is secure for use inside the function scope:

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OWULaki/2/edit)***

```
  function $(id) {                       
     return document.getElementById(id);
  }       
  function showImg() {
    var img = new Image();
    var div = document.getElementById('container');
    div.appendChild(img);
    img.src = "http://www.palomar.edu/images/assets/pclogo.jpg";
  }

  window.onload = function (){
     $("showImgJavaScript").onclick = showImg;       
  }; 

jQuery(function( $ ) { // secure alias !!!!!!!!!!!
    $( "#showImgjQuery").click(function() {
        $("#image").append("<img src='http://www.palomar.edu/images/assets/pclogo.jpg'>");
    });  
});
```

---

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OWULaki/1/edit)***

by wrapping your JS into an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression) you'll get read of your issue, cause in that case the inner `$` will be available for that **function scope**.

```
(function vanilla(){

    function $(id) {                       
       return document.getElementById(id);
    }       
    function showImg() {
      var img = new Image();
      var div = document.getElementById('container');
      div.appendChild(img);
      img.src = "http://www.palomar.edu/images/assets/pclogo.jpg";
    }

    window.onload = function (){
       $("showImgJavaScript").onclick = showImg;       
    }; 

}());


$(function() { 
    $( "#showImgjQuery").click(function() {
        $("#image").append("<img src='http://www.palomar.edu/images/assets/pclogo.jpg'>");
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, this really helps. i did not realize that the "$" is the conflicting issue.

Comment: @user2872778 yes, the only issue was the jQuery-alike way to return some element using the nifty `function $(id) {` but than voilá there's your issue :) Otherwise, beside the class-ID typo, your jQ seems OK and looks like you know how to handle with it! Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#showImgjQuery").click(function() {

        $( "#container" ).append("<img src='http://www.palomar.edu/images/assets/pclogo.jpg'>");
    });

});
```